# How to send styles from parent component to child component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to send style object from parent to a child component.
Parent.js:

```
const styles = theme => ({

  field: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 1,
  },
});

class Parent extends React.Component {
 render(){
  const {classes } = this.props
  return (
   <div>
    <Child className={classes.field} />
   </div>
  )
}
}
```

Child.js:

```
const styles = theme => ({

  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 2,
  },
});

class Child extends React.Component {
 render(){
  const {classes} = this.props
  return (
   <div>
    <Child className={classes.field} />
   </div>
  )
}
}
```

This returns the object classes of the Child component does not contains the style field contained in the Parent component. Is there any suggestion to send styles from Parent to Child ?

Comment: whats the use case for this?

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja this is a simple case to describe the issue, however I need to pass style from a parent to child component in my real project to override some values of style's object in the child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you created `const.styles` but you're calling `{classes.field}`

try change `styles` to `classes` or:

```
const { styles } = this.props
```

send to child via props:

```
 <Child className={styles.field} />
```

then

```
class Child extends React.Component {
 render(){
  const {styles} = this.props
  return (
   <div>
    <Child className={styles.field} />
   </div>
  )
}
```

and `className` to property i guess is not the best choice

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
// Parent component 
class Parent extends React.Component {
 render(){
  return (
   <View>
    <Child customStyle={styles.childStyle} />
   </View>
  )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 childStyle: {
   color: "red"
 }
});

// Child component

class Child extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (    
    <View>
        <Text style={[this.props.customStyle, styles.text]}></Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 14
  }
});
```

Comment: @ HarkiratSaluja which package is StyleSheet being imported from in this example?

Comment: @JeremyBrown react-native

Answer (score 0):

**In react-native**, you can pass styling as props from parent component to child component.

**Parent Component:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import ChildComponent from "./components/ChildComponent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ChildComponent
        data="Apply styling from parent component to child component"
        style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "red", fontWeight: "400" }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Child Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return <Text style={props.style}>{props.data}</Text>;
};

export default ChildComponent;
```